# Keep TextInputLayout always focused or keep label always expanded

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I was wondering if it's possible to always keep the label expanded regardless of whether or not there is text in the `EditText`. I looked around in the source and it is a using a `ValueAnimator` and a `counter` inside a `TextWatcher` to animate or not animate changes. Maybe I can set a custom `TextWatcher` with a custom `ValueAnimator` on the `EditText` inside the `TextInputLayout`?

Answer (score 10):

The current version of the `TextInputLayout` exists specifically to do one thing - show / hide the helper label depending on whether there's some text in the `EditText` or not. What you want is different behaviour, so you need a different widget than the `TextInputLayout`. This case is the perfect candidate to writing a custom view that will suit your needs.

That said, your idea of setting a custom `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` won't work either because `TextInputLayout` doesn't expose anything of it's internals that actually handle the animations - neither `updateLabelVisibility()`, `setEditText()`, the magic `Handler` that does the work or anything else. Of course we surely don't want to go the reflection path for a detail like this, so...

Just use [MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText)! It has the following property that does exactly what you want.

> **met_floatingLabelAlwaysShown**: Always show the floating label, instead of animating it in/out. False as default.

The library is quite stable (I'm using it in two different projects myself) and has plenty of options to customise. Hope it helps!

Comment: Good catch regarding the material edittext lib, I've seen that lib before but I think I can extrapolate some logic to create a custom component specifically for my use case :thumbs_up:

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my first paragraph - that's a perfect candidate for a custom text view. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

For me with support design 23.3.0 it works to use

```
              <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="wow such hint"
              app:hintEnabled="true"
              app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
              />
```

Comment: This doesn't work for v25.0.2; Label is not expanded when text is empty.

Answer (score 8):

Despite the top answer, I still simply came up with a Java Reflection solution to achieve the desired behavior (using `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` from `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`):

```
/**
 * Creation Date: 3/20/19
 *
 * @author www.flx-apps.com
 */
public class CollapsedHintTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
    Method collapseHintMethod;

    public CollapsedHintTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CollapsedHintTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CollapsedHintTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        setHintAnimationEnabled(false);

        try {
            collapseHintMethod = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredMethod("collapseHint", boolean.class);
            collapseHintMethod.setAccessible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ignored) {
            ignored.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();
        try {
            collapseHintMethod.invoke(this, false);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Java Reflection is of course never pretty, but in my case, it just was the more handy solution than creating a similar looking widget, and the linked library seemed outdated and abandoned… :/

Don't forget to add the respective ProGuard rules if you use it:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout {
    private void collapseHint;
}
```

Comment: Works for me too. A real solution! Thanks for share.

Answer (score 4):

The new attribute `app:expandedHintEnabled` (since 1.3.0) solves this problem without subclassing and other hacks.

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/810

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, but I want to add that you need to set `app:expandedHintEnabled` as `false` and use the `hint` attribute from `TextInputLayout` to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick you can use that will allow you to put the label hint in the layout and the textbox hint in the edittext without them clashing. It will work better than the above reflection solution as well, as it prevents the original bad drawing from happening and doesn't require you to address minification/proguar settings, since it does class-to-class comparison.

Subclass TextInputEditText as follows:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.R
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

class MonkeyedTextInputEditText @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.editTextStyle) : TextInputEditText(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    @Override
    override fun getText(): Editable? {
        val text = super.getText()
        if (!text.isNullOrEmpty())
            return text
        /* We want this expression in TextInputLayout.java to be true if there's a hint set:
         *        final boolean hasText = editText != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText());
         * But for everyone else it should return the real value, so we check the caller.
         */
        if (!hint.isNullOrEmpty() && Thread.currentThread().stackTrace[3].className == TextInputLayout::class.qualifiedName)
            return SpannableStringBuilder(hint)
        return text
    }
}
```

Then your layouts can look like:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...
    android:hint="YOUR LABEL TEXT"
    ...
    >

    <yourapp.MonkeyedTextInputEditText
        ...
        android:hint="YOUR PLACEHOLDER TEXT"
        ...
        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: There are two problems, when you need to change the hint in your `TextInputEditText` dynamically (or even add it or remove it dynamically). First problem is, that the `TextInputEditText` implementation of the hint property returns the hint of the parent layout, when the hint is not set, so you have to use your own property for setting the EditText hint, this property keeps local copy of the hint value, which is used in the condition for returning the fake `getText` result and its forwards value to the original hint property.

Comment: The second problem is, that the `TextInputLayout` is not refreshing (expending) when you set hint to an EditText that had no hint before. So you need to call `updateLabelState` method using reflection. My solution https://gist.github.com/AlmightyCZ/527e11ad07ec67007208c2f5519a296c